# Установка библиотеки VariKN в Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu

Всем привет! Начинаю работать на Python с OpusFilter — инструмент для фильтрации и объединения параллельных корпусов (переводы с иностранных языков). Не могу победить модуль VariKN. Нашел по нему очень мало инфы, в технической документации описана установка, но она не очень понятна мне пока. За день установил Ubuyntu (на Windows вообще многие библиотеки не ставились), установил рекомендуемый Python-3.8, PyCarm, скачал проект с Github (https://github.com/Helsinki-NLP/OpusFilter), установил все библиотеки в REDME и Setup, проверил установку в ручную, отдельно устанавливал VariKN, он вроде и установился, но при запуске файла opustools выдает ошибку, что VariKN не грузится. Техдокументацию тоже читал, допускаю, что чего-то пока не понял, мало опыта.
Может есть у кого опыт установки и работы с этим инструментом?
Не судите строго, я еще стажер))

Ошибка ниже:

Could not load varikn, language model filtering not supported
Please set enviroment variable EFLOMAL_PATH to use word alignment scores
usage: opusfilter [-h] [--overwrite] [--last LAST] [--single SINGLE]
[--n-jobs N_JOBS]
CONFIG
opusfilter: error: the following arguments are required: CONFIG

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с этой же проблемой, получилось собрать библиотеку после использования команды:

```
cmake --build .
```

Полный список команд:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
cmake --build .
```

Собранное для проекта, будет лежать по пути:

**variKN/build/lib/python**

Comment: А как запускаете фильтрацию? Запускаете файл opusfilter через терминал, или run? И в какую директорию помещаете исходный файл с переводимым текстом?